# What storage method in the Azure Logic App

Tags: storage, azure-logic-apps

I'm new to the Azure Logic App, and I'm creating an app that needs the date, time and status for the previous run.
I can see this information in the run history for the app, but is there a way I can retrieve this and use it in my logic app?

The first thought was to create a table in SQL database, but it's a bit overambitious for only 1 table.

Is there a smart way to solve this in logic app?

Comment: Hi, may I know if you want to get the date, time, status of previous actions in the next action in one logic app ? Or get the date, time, status of a previous logic app running in another logic app ?

Comment: I'm not clear about your requirement, but if your requirement is to get the running information of one logic app in another logic app, you can refer to the solution I provided below. If it helps your problem, please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) it as answer(click on the check mark beside my answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). Thanks in advance~

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is to get the running information of one logic app in another logic app, you can refer to the solution below:

**1.** Create a "Log Analytics workspace" and add "Logic Apps Management" in it, you can refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/monitor-logic-apps-log-analytics#install-logic-apps-management-solution).

**2.** Create a new logic app and configure the "Diagnostic settings", please refer to the steps on this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/monitor-logic-apps-log-analytics#set-up-azure-monitor-logs).

**3.** After completing the configuration above, please wait for a few minutes and then run your logic app serval times for test (The logs in Log Analytics workspace will be a little bit of a delay, I wait for more than 30 minutes. It just show the logs of running instance which run after 30 minutes of the "Diagnostic settings" deployment).

**4.** Go to your "Log Analytics workspace", click "Workspace summary" --> "Logs".
[image]

There are four query samples for logic app to query the logs, you can also write some other queries to query the logs which you want.
[image]

I just use the third query sample to query the logs distribution by status, we can see there are two success and one failed.
[image]

**5.** Then create another logic app to get the logs. First add "Run query and list results(preview)" action and copy the query sample to the "Query" box.
[image]
[image]

**6.** Run the logic app, we can see the logs result show as below format.

```
{
  "value": [
    {
      "LogicAppName": "huryLogLogic",
      "NumberOfExecutions": 1,
      "RunStatus": "Failed",
      "Error": "ActionFailed"
    },
    {
      "LogicAppName": "huryLogLogic",
      "NumberOfExecutions": 2,
      "RunStatus": "Succeeded",
      "Error": ""
    }
  ]
}
```